# What encryption is this? Thinking it's not web-based

Tags: encryption, decryption

I'm not too familiar with encryption and I was hoping someone could tell me? Thanks for any help.

9A84EE2C1DD3218B4BABACA0916E7E1335C5299E

Comment: Where did you get this from? Without any contect we just can guess.

Comment: That looks like hexadecimal, but may or may not actually be an encrypted message. Since it represents 20 bytes, it could be the result of an SHA-1 calculation. Is there any context for this string?

Comment: That looks like [Hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). Beyond that, nobody is going to be able to tell you much.

Comment: No context, it was posted as a "challenge" on a site.

Comment: hexadecimal or a SHA-1 hash

Comment: lol, so you want us to do the challenge for you?

Comment: SHA-1 is breakable, check rainbow tables or brute force it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a sequence of 40 [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) characters. As such, they represent the value of a sequence of exactly 20 bytes.

Then these bytes could be just about anything, but "20 bytes" *suggests* the use of the hash function [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) or a derivative thereof. SHA-1 is *hashing*, not encryption (although there are some misguided souls who keep on ranting about "password encryption" in that case -- some people are just beyond redemption).

Of course there are many other ways in which 20 bytes could end up somewhere. Even among hash functions, SHA-1 is not the only one which has an output of 20 bytes; it just is the most common.